# pythonrc.py is not loading in interactive mode

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu

I've added a .pythonrc.py script to my home directory with the commands below:

```
import os
import sys
print 'Welcome'
```

I've confirmed that it is actually executable by running `python .pythonrc.py` and by loading the python interpreter and running `execfile('.pythonrc.py')`.  However, when I start interactive mode, it seems that the script is never being loaded.  Calls to methods in os or sys return errors that os or sys are not defined.  Has anyone seen this before?  Any suggestions?

I'm running Python 2.6 on an Ubuntu 10 server.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem.  I *don't* have PYTHONSTARTUP set in my environment, yet Python still loads ~/.pythonrc.py when I run a shell.  I would conclude that it's built-in default behavior, but I can find no reference of this feature on python.org, so I'm left mystified.

Comment: Figured it out - it's Django magic (sigh): https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/core/management/commands/shell.py

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should set the Environment variable [PYTHONSTARTUP](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) to point to the start up script that you created.

In Ubuntu you can edit the ~/.bashrc file and add this line in the end:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc.py
```

Now you **should** start a new shell and run python.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Corey Kennedy: Glad it help :)

Comment: or you don't need to start a new shell, just run `source .bashrc` after editing it.

Comment: or run `exec bash` then start Python interactive shell, in order to avoid having to start new terminal emulator instance. <-- in Linux distro with Bash Unix shell